# Either begin from or on

Tags: prepositions

What is the error in the following sentence

> The examination begins from Monday next week.

On many of the websites I found that it should be **on** instead of **from**, but I think from is correct here, although **on** is also correct but with a difference in meaning.

Am I right?

Comment: It's usual to collocate start with from and begin with on.  Can you verify there is only one exam and it goes beyond Monday, or if there are other exams and the sessions begin on Monday?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples to illustrate when to use "from" to indicate a duration of time vs. using "on" (or "at") to indicate a particular point in time.

The movie opens on Friday.
The movie will be showing from Friday, June 2 until Friday, June 16.
The celebration starts at 7:00 pm.
The celebration lasts for two hours from 7:00 to 9:00.
I will meet you at the lake on Thursday.
Let's stay at the lake from Thursday to Sunday.