# Starting in [year] v. starting from [year]

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to say 'starting/beginning from [year]' or 'starting/beginning in [year]'? Like

> Beginning in 2007, smartphones started to gradually squeeze conventional button devices out of the cell phone market.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Either begin from or on](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/250953/either-begin-from-or-on)

Comment: **As of 2007**, etc. However, "beginning in" or "starting in" can be used though they are heavier than "as of". Use of either verb requires the ing form....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Beginning in" or "starting in" followed by a year is common and correct for referring to something that occurred over multiple years. "Starting from" is less common, and sounds somewhat non-standard (to my American English ears) for time spans.

"Beginning in" and "From" are roughly equivalent in meaning when used to introduce a time span. Another phrase must follow "beginning in" such as "and continuing to" or "and up until," while "from" is used for simple constructions such as  "From 2010 to 2020, smartphone sales increased an average of 30 percent each year."

Comment: Are you sure that I MUST follow 'beginning in' with 'up until' or a similar phrase?

Comment: Not in all cases, no. I assumed the statement would describe the whole time period (start and end); if not, then the phrasing "Beginning in" is fine without "and continuing to..." or similar.